# PRAW `extra_query` field in `Subreddit.submission()` doesn't work

Tags: reddit, praw

I am trying to use the `extra_query` field in the `Subreddit.submissions()` method of PRAW, as described in the documentation [here](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html?highlight=submissions#praw.models.Subreddit.submissions).

Here is my code:

```
import praw
import json
import time

configFile = open("config.json", 'r')
configData = json.load(configFile)

now = time.time()-60

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=configData['user']['client_id'],
                     client_secret=configData['user']['client_secret'],
                     user_agent=configData['user']['user_agent'])

for submission in reddit.subreddit('all').submissions(now-3600, now, 'site:imgur.com'):
    print(submission.url)
```

This gives no results, even though when I removed the search query to just have `submissions(now-3600, now)` there are results indicated with an `imgur.com` domain. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I need:

```
for submission in reddit.subreddit('all').submissions(now-(3600), now, "(or site:'imgur.com')"):
```